# AutoMapper: custom conversion from int to enum

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following classes:

```
public class StatusSqlModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public enum UploadStatus
{
    Created,
    InProgress,
    Succeeded,
    Failed,
    Cancelled
}
```

Using AutoMapper library how to convert 'Id' from StatusSqlModel to 'UploadStatus' enum so that the mapping result will be the following:

> 1 -> Created 2 -> InProgress, 3 -> Succeeded, 4 -> Failed, 5 ->
> Cancelled

Thanks.

Comment: `enum UploadStatus{ Created = 1, InProgress, Succeeded, Failed, Cancelled }` The numeric values will match.

Comment: This is a domain enum and by requirements I should not put numbers in it.

Comment: :) That doesn't make much sense. A C# enum is an integer regardless. And it leads to a painful, manual solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer to convert from StatusSqlModel to UploadStatus

To convert from the incoming model we take care about the Id and the Name property. If another strategy is needed, you can adopt the given code accordingly:

```
cfg.CreateMap<StatusSqlModel, UploadStatus>()
    .ConstructUsing((model, _) => model switch
    {
        { Id: 1, Name: nameof(UploadStatus.Created) } => UploadStatus.Created,
        { Id: 2, Name: nameof(UploadStatus.InProgress) } => UploadStatus.InProgress,
        { Id: 3, Name: nameof(UploadStatus.Succeeded) } => UploadStatus.Succeeded,
        { Id: 4, Name: nameof(UploadStatus.Failed) } => UploadStatus.Failed,
        { Id: 5, Name: nameof(UploadStatus.Cancelled) } => UploadStatus.Cancelled,
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{model.Id} {model.Name}"),
    });
```

#### Wrong answer to convert from UploadStatus to StatusSqlModel

Like @LucianBargaoanu already mentioned in the comment, it is higly recommended to ensure, that the raw values of the enum itself matches the numbers used in other places. Due to this fact I would recommend to slightly change your enum to look like this:

```
public enum UploadStatus
{
    Created = 1,
    InProgress,
    Succeeded,
    Failed,
    Cancelled
}
```

With this it is very simple to create a matching AutoMapper for your needs:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<UploadStatus, StatusSqlModel>()
        .ConstructUsing(status => new StatusSqlModel 
        {
            Id = (int)status,
            Name = status.ToString()
        });
});
var mapper = new Mapper(config);

var enums = Enum.GetValues<UploadStatus>();

foreach (var value in enums)
{
    var result = mapper.Map<StatusSqlModel>(value);
    Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(result));
}
```

If you can't take that route and you need to completely build up the model from the given enum value you can try this code:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<UploadStatus, StatusSqlModel>()
        .ConstructUsing((status, _) => status switch
            {
                UploadStatus.Created => new StatusSqlModel { Id = 1, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.Created) },
                UploadStatus.InProgress => new StatusSqlModel { Id = 2, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.InProgress) },
                UploadStatus.Succeeded => new StatusSqlModel { Id = 3, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.Succeeded) },
                UploadStatus.Failed => new StatusSqlModel { Id = 4, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.Failed) },
                UploadStatus.Cancelled => new StatusSqlModel { Id = 5, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.Cancelled) },
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(status.ToString()),
            });
});
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
```

Last but not least, cause the possible number of instance for your StatusSqlModel is known, you could already predefine them and only use these:

```
public sealed class StatusSqlModel
{
    public required int Id { get; init; }

    public required string Name { get; init; }

    private StatusSqlModel() { }

    public static readonly StatusSqlModel Created = new() { Id = 1, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.Created) };
    public static readonly StatusSqlModel InProgress = new() { Id = 2, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.InProgress) };
    public static readonly StatusSqlModel Succeeded = new() { Id = 3, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.Succeeded) };
    public static readonly StatusSqlModel Failed = new() { Id = 4, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.Failed) };
    public static readonly StatusSqlModel Cancelled = new() { Id = 5, Name = nameof(UploadStatus.Cancelled) };
}

var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<UploadStatus, StatusSqlModel>()
        .ConstructUsing((status, _) => status switch
            {
                UploadStatus.Created => StatusSqlModel.Created,
                UploadStatus.InProgress => StatusSqlModel.InProgress,
                UploadStatus.Succeeded => StatusSqlModel.Succeeded,
                UploadStatus.Failed => StatusSqlModel.Failed,
                UploadStatus.Cancelled => StatusSqlModel.Cancelled,
                _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(status.ToString()),
            });
});
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
```

Comment: Helpful but i think he wanted it the other way round `how to convert 'Id' from StatusSqlModel to 'UploadStatus' enum`

Comment: @Ralf: You're right. Give me a few minutes. 